# How do I set up online hosting for an eclipse war file and initial MySQL server data currently on my laptop?

Tags: mysql, eclipse, hibernate, web, web-hosting

I built this small web app in eclipse (has Jsp pages, java interface, and hibernate for database connectivity).

Now I want to host this as a website. I have the basic idea about web hosting, but what about the database ?? How do I connect the website with that database ??

In short...

1: How do I host a website which is currently in the form of a war file ?

2: How do I put the data which is present in database online (if there is anything called online database) and then keep it connected with my web app ?

Answer (score 1):

To host a java based website, you would need to use a publicly accessible application server such as Tomcat set up to deploy to. [Openshift](http://openshift.com/) is a free cloud hosting service suited for this task. If you create a new Tomcat app, they would provide you with a git url to push your application to, which would then be deployed on their service

Binding the service to a database would be specific to the host you are using but for Openshift you would add something to this effect to your hibernatecontext.xml (if you using MySQL)

`<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
       <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
       <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}:${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}/${OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}" />
       <property name="username" value="${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME}" />
       <property name="password" value="${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD}" />
   </bean>`